# How to replace self (UIView) with another UIView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview

View A has a button upon clicking it, we go to view B

- View B does not retain a pointer to view A.
- From view B, i'd like to load view A back (programmatically)

Effectively, i'd like to kill B and replace it with A.

I was thinking that the following should work but, it does not

Calling from View B

```
ViewController *main = [ViewController new];    
[self addSubview:[main view]];
```

What am i missing please?

Comment: 15 yrs later .. you just use container views for this purpose https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399061/how-to-add-a-subview-that-has-its-own-uiviewcontroller-in-objective-c/23403979#23403979

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think the easiest way to do this would be by having a `UIViewController` with an `IBOutlet` to both `UIView` objects. You can add and design them both in the interface builder and just set one of them (view B) as hidden (it's a property in `UIView`).
Then, you could specify a button action to toggle the visibility of view B.

I must add though that there are constructs for implementing screen flows, such as the `NavigationController`. In your case, however, you might also consider the use of the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method.

It all depends really, but in general it's better practice to make a seperate `UIViewController` for each `UIView` in your application.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Right. Assuming i use the Xcode4.2 and Segues, how can this be done?

Comment: Well i'm not a big fan of segues and the storyboard, but the idea remains the same. Add 2 views to your viewcontroller in the scene (on the left) and put one of them as hidden. I think that in your case you don't even need segues. Unless of course you're going to take my advice and split your 2 views into 2 viewControllers. Then, to present a view (like view B) modally from another view (like view A), you can add a button to view A and ctrl+drag to the other viewController. On release, it'll ask you what kind of transition you'd like to use. Choose modal to present view B as a modal view.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like you're looking for a navigation controller.  You can easily take away a navigation controllers NavBar and take away the animations if you don't want them - but this would achieve exactly what you're looking for.