# iPhone: Replacing UIView with itself (resetting view)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIView that represents a game screen.  I have a reset button allowing users to replay that level.  For the reset though I want to reset ALL UI controls to their default state as upon completion various animations take place that fade in/out text and move around images etc.

What I would like to do is replace the existing UIView with another copy of itself (with animation).  How can I do this whilst not breaking the `UINavigation` stack? When a user presses back on the new screen I want them to goto the original parent `UIView` and not the game screen that was replaced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8247235/684934 might help.  Looks related.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar using a mask view.

1. Create a mask view, a UIView set as your starting view (or just an image).
2. Animate a transition from your game view to your mask view.
3. Reset your game view.
4. Remove your mask view, showing your game view.

Doing so your UINavigation stack won't be broken, because you actually use just one active view (game view) and a static mask to cover your view for transition.

Answer (score 0):

On the top of your controller stack you presumably have controller that "owns the game view"?

I also assume that you are using a custom view within your controller to do most of the view stuff.

If this is the case, then you should be able to alloc, init another instance of your game view which will be in default state. Set it's alpha to 0.0f and add it to the view hierarchy, then animate its alpha to 1.0f and in the animation completion block remove and release th sold view that you no longer need.

Alternatively you could define the start condition, positions, values etc. and then just animate back to them when the button is pressed.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey, this is mostly correct, I currently reset my custom view but resetting all the other UI elements on the view is causing me a headache :)

Comment: What other things are you trying to reset?

Comment: Well I have the game board (which is just a bitmap I alter) and then various UI elements such as labels, and supporting images.  These all get moved about on completion so will have to be reset

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have code to initialize all of you subviews and game-related data members right?

move that code to a separate method and have the reset button call the method.

I usually have a `-setupSubviews` method on each custom view i create and i call it each time i need to reset my view to its original state, for example:

```
- (void)setupSubviews
{
    _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self addSubview:_titleLabel];

    _activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self addSubview:_activityIndicator];

    _loading = NO;
}
```